# Wpf checkbox on datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I've a checkbox on a datagrid but I've a problem:
if I click on the checkbox the first time I'm not be able to check the checkbox because I think WPF select the row.
Do you have a solution for this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post an example of your XAML? You won't get much help here with out code examples. Show what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow what you mean, you want to be able to check the checkbox with one click.
You can just ensure there's a checkbox in the cell initially:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Chk" MinWidth="40" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Set the bound property to false initially

```
public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false;
```

Comment: I resolved with your solution 
but I had to replace DatagridCheckboxColumn with DatagridTemplateColumn and internal Checkbox like your example.
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use the solution from a post, you're kind of supposed to mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set up a trigger to take the hover over event and select the row.  This way you will just use one mouse click to check/ uncheck the box:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- The following style trigger allows for a single click to set/unset a checkbox in the datagrid-->
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```